# Как из numpy array создать DataFrame без потери типов данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    # создаем таблицу общую для X и Y
    data = np.array([[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 45],
                       ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0'], 
                       ['мультики', 'куклы', 'дискотеки', 'учеба', 'работа', 'дача']])
    
    names = pd.DataFrame(data.T, columns = ['age', 'gender', 'genre'])
    names.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
age       6 non-null object
gender    6 non-null object
genre     6 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 224.0+ bytes
```

То есть, столбец `age` с `Int` стал строковым.

Как при создании DataFrame установить тип, чтоб он не исказился?

Answer (score 2):

Элегантного решения данной задачи не существует по той причине, что `Numpy.NDArray`, вне зависимости от размерности, может иметь только один тип данных и, соответственно, все данные будут преобразованы к наиболее общему типу данных, который способен хранить все данные. Чаще всего это будет тип данных - `object` (строка).

Поэтому либо создавайте DataFrame из отдельных столбцов:

```
In [35]: age = np.array([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 45])

In [36]: gender = np.array(['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0'])

In [37]: genre = np.array(['мультики', 'куклы', 'дискотеки', 'учеба', 'работа', 'дача'])

In [38]: names = pd.DataFrame({"age": age, "gender": gender, "genre": genre})

In [39]: names.dtypes
Out[39]:
age        int32
gender    object
genre     object
dtype: object
```

либо преобразуйте типы данных в DF уже после создания:

```
In [43]: new = names.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")

In [44]: new.dtypes
Out[44]:
age        int64
gender     int64
genre     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: names[["age"]] = names[["age"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)

Comment: @svil, `names["age"] = pd.to_numeric(names["age"], errors="coerce")`

Comment: Ещё можно `names['age'] = names['age'].astype('int')`

Comment: @strawdog, это сработает только в том случае если в столбце `age` будут только целые числа (или строки, которые могут быть преобразованы к целым)...